# Next unread message shortcut in Kmail message window

Tags: kde, kmail

I have Kmail set up without a message preview to save space on my screen.  I am trying to find a way to set up a keyboard shortcut to go to the next unread message when I have a message open in its own window.

I tried using + and I tried the space bar.  Neither worked and I think setting up a global shortcut may be the way to go.  However, I cannot put anything in the field "global" in the list of keyboard shortcuts.

Any other ideas how to go to the next unread message?